# inserting some rows from one table to another by changing value of one column

Tags: sql, sql-server, import

I have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Question] (
    [QuesID]    INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Body]      NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [O1]        NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [O2]        NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [O3]        NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [O4]        NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [UserID]    NVARCHAR (50)  NULL,
    [QuesDate]  DATETIME       NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([QuesID] ASC)
);
```

And I want to

```
select * from Question where UserID=N'admin'
```

then insert what I selected, to this table but change the UserID from admin to another value. Notice that I don't need to select QuesID because its PRIMARY KEY.

Comment: Why is the question tagged MySQL but the syntax is SQL Server (or perhaps Sybase)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
insert into Question ([Body], [O1], [O2], [O3], [O4], [UserID])
select [Body], [O1], [O2], [O3], [O4], 'newUserID' 
from Question 
where UserID = N'admin'
```

Comment: It was so sweet like a candy :D
thank you very much.
hope to see you and your perfect answers in my posts again :)

Answer (score 0):

In an `insert ... select` statement, you can easily replace a column by a literal value:

```
insert  YourTable
        (UserID, col1, col2, ...)
select  N'anothervalue'
,       col1
,       col2
,       ...
from    YourTable
where   UserID = N'admin'
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `insert . . . select` is standard SQL that works in most databases.  Here is an example, using your table format:

```
insert into Question(Body, O1, O2, O3, O4, UserId, QuesDate)
    select Body, O1, O2, O3, O4, N'NewValue' as UserId, QuesDate
    from Question
    where UserId = N'admin';
```